# Deploying Customized JAR in AWS failing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, emr

I am trying to deploy a customized JAR in AWS (Map Reduce). I have to read files from S3. The paths to S3 are given as command line arguments. While the cluster is running, I see the following in the 'Steps' section of the Cluster:

```
Status:FAILED
Reason:Illegal Argument.
Log File:s3://aws-logs-502743756123-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/j-3U1NGY5JNUBK2/steps/s-O3W3I4RU4NXS/stderr.gz
Details:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3n://****/input, expected: hdfs://ip-172-31-45-130.ec2.internal:8020
JAR location: s3://****/ChainMapperDriver.jar
Main class: None
Arguments: ChainMapperDriver s3://****/input s3://****/output/
Action on failure: Terminate cluster
```

ChainMapperDriver is the name of the Main Class.

Do I have to do anything in the JAVA code that I have written to handle the case when the files are in S3? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `s3n://****/input`?   are you sure that's right?

Comment: Yes. s3://****/Input is  a folder containing files. I tried giving  s3://****/Input/ as well.

Comment: I meant to say that I tried with s3n://****/input, s3://****/Input and s3://****/Input/, because one of blogs I read was suggesting to use s3n:// instead of s3://.

Comment: s3n:// or s3:// provide the same function at least with the newer EMR AMI versions. The error is probably coming from your Driver class. Can you post  your driver code?